# Can anyone tell what is media query min-width and max-width for Google Nexus 6 android phone

Tags: responsiveness

What is media query width for Google Nexus 6 android phone.
I had tried below media query

```
@media (min-width: 670px) and (max-width: 740px)
```

but this is not for nexus, I tried more and more but cant find exact width for this phone. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The correct media query for Google Nexus is as below :

@media (min-device-width: 412px) and (max-device-width: 690px)
{
..
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1440px) and (max-device-width : 2560px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3.5){}
```

But I would recommend to use some generic approach like bootstrap does. The same Nexus 6 could have different browsers and different browser could have different view port.

Comment: I tried this one too, but it was not working. The correct one I found is  :   @media (min-device-width: 412px) and (max-device-width: 690px)

Comment: so add it as answer to your own question and accept it - mb some one would look for this as well as you

Answer (score 0):

I just used this and it worked for me. Portrait & Landscape queries

```
@media only screen 
   and (min-device-width: 412px) 
   and (max-device-width: 412px) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
   and (orientation: portrait) { 

}
@media only screen 
   and (min-device-width: 732px) 
   and (max-device-width: 732px) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
   and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```